# generar nueva pagina php cada vez que se necesite

Tags: php, html

necesito crear una nueva pagina cada vez que genero cierta parte html,
mediante el primer ciclo si logro que en mi pagina 'principal' se generen un titulo y un contenido que extraje de dos variables que obtuve de una base de datos pero luego me gustaría poner cada titulo y cada contenido en una nueva pagina, se que tal vez se soluciona con un ciclo pero la verdad estoy perdido, soy un novato en php.

```
    <?php

         include('conexion.php');

        $sql="SELECT * FROM tics";

      $resul=$link->query($sql);

         ?>

                <?php while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()):


                $t=$fila['tit'];
                $c=$fila['con'];


                ?>

                <?php 


  $contenido = "<html> <body class'hola5'> <h1>  $t </h1> <p>   $c  
     </p>  </body> </html>"; 


                $fp = fopen('new.php', 'w');
                      fwrite($fp, $contenido);

    //parte que intente crear una nueva pagina, funciona solo con 
      el ultimo registro //

       ?>

 //parte html que si me funciona generando cada registro en su 
respectiva etiqueta//

           <div class="card-body">
       <a href="new.php">  <h2 class="card-title"> <?= $t;?> </h2> <p>  
     <?= $c; ?> </p> </a>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    Posted on January 1, 2017 by
                    <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </div>
            </div>



<?php
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que estás preguntando. Querés escribir en un archivo en cada ciclo del `while`? Dónde cierra el `while`? El `fopen()` abre y escribe siempre el mismo archivo, por eso ves solo el contenido del último elemento del loop.

Comment: en la ultima linea del codigo que subi termina el while, seria algo asi       
 **<?php endwhile; ?> y lo que me gustaria hacer es cada registro o cada par de variables que obtengo de mi base de datos ponerlas en un archivo nuevo, por ejemplo el ciclo si me inserta en mi pagina 'base' los 3 pares de variables que obtuve pero solo me agrega un par al archivo,me gustaria generar en este caso 3 archivos espero explicarme.

Comment: Entonces ésta línea `$fp = fopen('new.php', 'w');` deberías modificarla para que cada archivo sea único. Si agregás un contador, podrías hacer algo así: `$fp = fopen('new' . $i . '.php', 'w');`.

Comment: gracias me agrada tu respuesta, pero es que todo esto es en base a una base de datos entonces como generaría el contador, no hay problema si constantemente se van a estar agregando registros? otra cosa como haria para que cada nuevo archivo generado se agrege a un link en una etiqueta html ?